# Como trocar o schema do database presente config.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuração

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação já finalizada desenvolvida em Node.js/Expressjs.

No atual momento meu problema é: 95% da aplicação **usa o schema A**, mas o novo módulo que estou criando **precisa usar o schema B**.

Como eu faço essa alteração em tempo de execução sem alterar o **config.js**. *A menos que haja uma configuração nele que não impacte a aplicação.*

Exemplo de query do sistema:

```
var query = "select * from " + config.bd.schema + ".user_types ;";
```

As novas queries deve ser assim:

```
var query = "select * from b.user_types ;";
```

---

## Erro que estou recebendo

```
Report.js - getData() >>> column_3 >>>  select * from dash.user_types where column_3 = 777
/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/models/Report.js:69
        if(err) throw err;
                ^

error: syntax error at or near "select"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:534:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:361:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/patrick/Workspace/company/project/admin/proj/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

---

## config.js

```
module.exports={
    port: 3002,
    base: "/",
    elms_por_pag:5,
    session_timeout:30,
    bd:{
        host:'localhost',
        user:'****',
        password:'****',
        database:'*****',
        schema:'a'
    },
    email:{
        link_email:"http://projetos.exemplo.com.br",
        debug:false,
        host:"",
        port:0,
        name:"Projeto",
        secure:true,
        username:"",
        password:""
    }
}
```

---

Se precisarem de mais informação me avisem.

Comment: E que tal no novo modulo fazer `var configB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('./config'))); configB.bd.schema = 'b';` Dessa maneira dentro do módulo tens o config certo. Ou então criar uma entrada nesse config.js para outros modulos. Tudo depende se é uma excepção ou se vale a pena repensar a logica.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar aqui @Sergio

Answer (score 0):

**Erro meu pessoal...**

Não postei a query original aqui por questões de segurança da empresa, mas na query tinha o seguinte campo:

```
vagas_disponíveis
```

Disponíveis **com acento**. No banco também.

O problema era: usando o psql ou o dbvis, a query executava normalmente, mas já no Node.js ele acusava erro por conta do acento. Que eu considero correto é claro, pois não deveria existir acento no nome de uma coluna - *eu não fiz isso haha*

Foi só fazer o rename da coluna e alterar a query e funcionou.

Desde já agradeço.